# Can't add a custom image upload adapter plugin to ckeditor 5 with vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ckeditor, inertiajs, ckeditor5

I am trying to make a custom image upload plugin for ckrditor5 with Vue js / Inertia / Vite Js / Laravel,
I read the documentation and make it exactly like the guide, but I got this error in the console.

```
app.js:70 TypeError: PluginConstructor is not a constructor
    at plugincollection.js:330:52
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at loadPlugins (plugincollection.js:328:39)
    at PluginCollection.init (plugincollection.js:158:33)
    at ClassicEditor.initPlugins (editor.js:216:29)
    at classiceditor.js:188:28
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ClassicEditor.create (classiceditor.js:186:16)
    at Proxy.mounted (ckeditor.ts:135:15)
    at runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2675:88
```

I tried to copy the **document example** to test it but again I get the error and ckeditor does not show up.

here is my code:

```
// Script Section   
import { ref } from "vue";
import { ClassicEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic"; 

class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor(loader) {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    // Starts the upload process.
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file.then(
            (file) =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this._initRequest();
                    this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
                    this._sendRequest(file);
                })
        );
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
        if (this.xhr) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }

    // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = (this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest());

        // Note that your request may look different. It is up to you and your editor
        // integration to choose the right communication channel. This example uses
        // a POST request with JSON as a data structure but your configuration
        // could be different.
        xhr.open("POST", "http://example.com/image/upload/path", true);
        xhr.responseType = "json";
    }

    // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;

        xhr.addEventListener("error", () => reject(genericErrorText));
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", () => reject());
        xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const response = xhr.response;

            // This example assumes the XHR server's "response" object will come with
            // an "error" which has its own "message" that can be passed to reject()
            // in the upload promise.
            //
            // Your integration may handle upload errors in a different way so make sure
            // it is done properly. The reject() function must be called when the upload fails.
            if (!response || response.error) {
                return reject(
                    response && response.error
                        ? response.error.message
                        : genericErrorText
                );
            }

            // If the upload is successful, resolve the upload promise with an object containing
            // at least the "default" URL, pointing to the image on the server.
            // This URL will be used to display the image in the content. Learn more in the
            // UploadAdapter#upload documentation.
            resolve({
                default: response.url,
            });
        });

        // Upload progress when it is supported. The file loader has the #uploadTotal and #uploaded
        // properties which are used e.g. to display the upload progress bar in the editor
        // user interface.
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", (evt) => {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Prepares the data and sends the request.
    _sendRequest(file) {
        // Prepare the form data.
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append("upload", file);

        // Important note: This is the right place to implement security mechanisms
        // like authentication and CSRF protection. For instance, you can use
        // XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() to set the request headers containing
        // the CSRF token generated earlier by your application.

        // Send the request.
        this.xhr.send(data);
    }
}

const MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin = (editor) => {
    editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
        return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
    };
};

const editor = ref(ClassicEditor);

const editorConfig = ref({

    extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin],

    /** everything else **/
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've already figured this out by now.

Change the following syntax:

```
const MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin = (editor) => {
```

To the function expression syntax:

```
const MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin = function(editor) {
```